# Data migration in Django

Tags: django, oracle, data-migration

We have a requirement to export the data from a Oracle db and load the exported data to the django models. The models in django are constructed manually based on the the same Oracle tables(same names/same columns/same datatypes). What is the best way of proceeding with this?
Pls let me know.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

- Enter your oracle db credentials and the details to the settings.py
- Do `./manage.py inspectdb` and create a models file
- Do `./manage.py dumpdata` that creates a django dump of your Oracle database data
- now update your settings with new database credentials.
- And then load the data `./manage.py loaddata`

Boom.

Comment: I'd give you an extra +1 if I could for the 'Boom' :o)

Comment: Thanks. This process needs to be automated. Can the 'settings' take in multiple dbs? In this case: 1 - Read the Oracle db settings 2. Write to mysql django models? This way, we dont have to update the settings with the new db credentials manually? Let me know

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py loaddata file.type` (sql, json, html, csv)
for data migration or data import from external file to django.

`python manage.py dumpdata file.type` (sql, json, html, csv)
for data export from django to external file.